# How do i make 2x cash gamepass script Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

So I was making a script that gives you 5 cash every minute, I also made a game pass for the script if someone owns the game pass they get double money as the Non-game pass holders. Here is my script
I Haven't any scripts to give cash but the problem is in the 2nd script block, the console print an error :

`09:10:57.466  ServerScriptService.CashGiver:6: attempt to index nil with 'UserId'  -  Server - CashGiver:6`

```
local Give5Cash = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Give5Cash")
local Give10Cash = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Give10Cash")

Give5Cash.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    print("Player Will Be Given 5 Cash")
end)

Give10Cash.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    print("Player Will Be Given 10 Cash")
end)
```

```
while wait() do
    local MPS = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
    local id = 16031172
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

    if MPS:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(player.UserId, id) then
        game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Give10Cash"):FireServer()
        print("Player Owns 2x Cash")
    else
        print("Players Doesnt Owns 2x Cash")
        game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Give5Cash"):FireServer()
    end 
    
    wait(5)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a way to solve this issue and I have got the answer for my question.
Here is how I did it I made `3` scripts in `ServerScriptService` with the name of `CashGiver5`, `CashGiver10`, and `CashGiverHandler`
here are the scripts I added to each script.
`CashGiver5`**:**

```
while wait(1) do
    print("Giving Player 5 Cash ")
    for i, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        player:WaitForChild("leaderstats").Cash.Value += 5
    end
end
```

`CashGiver10`**:**

```
while wait(1) do
    print("Giving Player 10 Cash ")
    for i, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        player:WaitForChild("leaderstats").Cash.Value += 10
    end
end
```

`CashGiverHandler`**:**

```
local MarketPlace = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local g = 16031172 -- DOUBLE CASH ID
    
    local Give5Script = game.ServerScriptService.CashGiver5
    local Give10Script = game.ServerScriptService.CashGiver10

    if MarketPlace:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(player.UserId, g) then
        Give5Script:Destroy()
    else
        Give10Script:Destroy()
    end
end)
```

**WHAT THE SCRIPT DOES?**

So basically the CashGiver scripts are basic scripts giving player `Cash` every second.
so the Handler script Destroys one of the scripts (s) when a player is added to the game.

Answer (score 2):

```
local player = Players.LocalPlayer
if MPS:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(player.UserId, id) then
```

...

Here you assign a nil value to `player` which you may not index but do.

From the [Roblox manual](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Players/LocalPlayer):

> **Players.LocalPlayer**
>
> NotReplicated
>
> This item is **not replicated across Roblox’s server/client boundary**.
>
> LocalPlayer is a read-only property which refers to the Player whose
> client is running the game.
>
> **This property is only defined for LocalScripts (and ModuleScripts
> required by them), as they run on the client. For the server (on which
> Script objects run their code), this property is nil.**

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: yes you read the manual... https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Roblox-Client-Server-Model.

Comment: you also have access to the players on the server side. there's just no LocalPlayer...